# Firebase - <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> xcode 8.2.1 - iOS 10.2

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I am getting the following warning in the console

*< FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO*

What does this warning mean in layman terms?

Details:

- iOS 10.2
- xcode 8.2.1
- Running on my device
- FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.8)
- Firebase 3.11.0

Comment: hey !   did you got any answer ???

Comment: @Najam afraid I didn't.